# JQuery - Showing just one item in nested divs

Tags: jquery, html

Let's say I have this HTML:

```
<div class="record">
       <a class="view-controls">Record 1</a>
       <br />
       <br />
  <div class="record-controls" style="display:none;">
       - Record Controls <br />
       - Record Controls <br />
  </div>
```

```
<div class="record">
    <a class="view-controls">Record 2</a>
    <br />
    <br />
  <div class="record-controls" style="display:none;">
      - Record Controls <br />
      - Record Controls <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

This is pulled from a database, therefore, each of the records will have some controls. I want the functionality that when you click on a record, the controls are displayed. Currently, the functionality works like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HVfaA/623/ but on clicking, the controls for all of the records show. I just want the one that has been clicked.

INCLUDED (JQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.view-controls').click(function()
  {
      $('.record-controls').show()

  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved in many ways, but since you don't use any kind of id's, the best bet would probably be to use...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.view-controls').click(function()
  {
      $(this).siblings('.record-controls').show();    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

use `this` as a current object and you can use [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to traverse to get sibling element with a specific class selector

```
$('.view-controls').click(function(){
      $('.record-controls').hide();
      $(this).siblings('.record-controls').show();
});
```

*this will show just one item at a time*

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HVfaA/626/)